# Odd behaviour of steady feedrate increase

Tags: marlin, g-code, anet-a8

For some weeks I noticed really odd behaviour on my OctoPi controlled Anet A8. I'm using an MKS Gen L board with TMC2208 on this and constellation worked for a year now.

When starting a print, I noticed the movements were really fast in spite of having an extra slow first layer. I adjust the feed rate to 100 % in Octoprint and it works normal. The final print has noticeable imperfections as it moves up. I check the feed rate after the print and it's at like 594 %. My G-code wouldn't specify such a value and I didn't find any related commands in there.

Further, if the printer is idle and I set `M220 S100` it returns FR:100 % when asked. If I make a homing move, wait and ask again, the value steadily rises. First FR:102 %, then FR:105 % after a minute and so on...

[image: OctoPi Terminal]

I think this behaviour might have started after using a G-code post-processed in Cura for different feed rates.

Does anyone have an idea how to tackle this? The printer was switched off several times already. If I implement an `M220` in the start G-code I assume it will still rise during the print.